# Why is foo object not changing?

Tags: javascript, closures

```
var foo = {'bar': 1};

function overwriteFoo(obj) {
   obj = foo;
   obj = {'bar': 2};
}

overwriteFoo(foo)
console.log(foo)
```

I thought that assigning foo to obj would make this work how I wanted. I thought that objects in javascript were sent by reference so why cant I reassign foo?

Answer (score 1):

As some people say, everything is pass-by-value, and objects' values are their reference. When you do `obj = {'bar': 2}`, you are **reassigning** `obj` to point to `{'bar': 2}` instead of pointing to `foo`. In fact, there is no way to just swap out an entire object like that. You can, however, change properties, as they essentially "dereference" the value:

```js
function overwriteFoo(obj) {
    obj.bar = 2;
}
overwriteFoo(foo);
console.log(foo); // will now be {bar: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assining a variable to another variable just returns the assigned variable's content.

Example:

```
var obj1 = {hello: 'hello'};
var obj2 = obj1;

alert(obj2);// will return hello: 'hello'

// BUt if you try to change obj2 to an object then obj1 will be just unassigned from obj2 but is not changed.
```